# Haskell: Is it possible to convert a Num to a Float?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I need to be able to convert generic numbers (instances of `Num`) to a `Float`. I searched Hoogle for a function with the signature `Num n => n -> Float`, but I couldn't find any such functions (although it may be possible to compose it). I also looked over the `Num` typeclass, and it doesn't seem to require instances of it to supply any conversion functions that may help me.

Why do I need to do this? I created a typeclass `Moveable` that defines operations to move a coordinate, and allowed it to work with any instance of `Num`, since the only thing required to move a coordinate is `+`, which is defined by `Num`. My end goal was to use this with Gloss (a graphics library), but unfortunately, Gloss only uses `Float`s. That means that if I'm storing the coordinate as a `Num`, I'll eventually need to convert it when I try to display an object.

I'd rather not make the number type more specific to so it'll work with Gloss. Does anyone have any ideas that could help?

Comment: why don't you store them as a `Float` if you need *Float* ? `Float` is an instance of `Num`, you can definitely make any functions you use that do `+` have a `Num` type restriction, and they'll take in a `Float` and return a `Float`...

Comment: I do know of a reasonable way to do what you're asking, I just doubt you really need to do it. It's not really a good idea to be doing because it's not going to be compile time guaranteed, conversions generally aren't which is why they're notoriously absent from Haskell as a whole. It's generally better to figure out how to make the type information available to the compiler so conversion isn't necessary vs. just forcing the conversion at runtime when you don't have a guarantee that the instance will be convertible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you "storing" your values as `Num` instead of `Float`? (How are you storing them? `Num` isn't even a type so you can't be storing them as that...)

```
Prelude> let y = 3.0::Float
Prelude> :t y
y :: Float
Prelude> let plus a b = a+b
Prelude> :t plus
plus :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t (plus y)
(plus y) :: Float -> Float
Prelude> plus y y
6.0
Prelude>
```

In conclusion:
Just use `Float`. Unless you have some reason not to?

---

As a rule, just remember that Haskell has very little in the way of conversions made available even though you *can* force them in a variety of ways if it's really necessary. The idiomatic approach to these things is always:

**Figure out how to make the type information available to the compiler so your types are gauranteed and you won't need to do conversions**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert arbitrary `Num` instances to `Float` because the `Num` class is too general to allow that.  For example, the [`Complex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Complex.html) type has `Num` instances.  What would it mean to "convert" a complex number to a real number?  I don't think there's any accepted sense of what that would mean.

Looking through Haskell's very confusing set of numeric classes, I think I can spot this pattern: "conversion" functions are generally only provided where there is something like an [**injective** mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) between the mathematical number sets that the types represent.  So for example, to convert an `Integral` instance to a real or complex number you have `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) -> a -> b`.  But there isn't a "conversion" function from `RealFrac` instances to integer types—you have to say explicitly whether you want `truncate`, `round`, `ceiling` or `floor`.

> I created a typeclass `Moveable` that defines operations to move a coordinate, and allowed it to work with any instance of `Num`, since the only thing required to move a coordinate is `+`, which is defined by `Num`.

Since `Complex` has `Num` instances, your choice here means that you've admitted into your model the concept of moving coordinates by complex amounts.  Does that make sense in your application?  It sounds to me like you need to do one of the following:

1. Choose a narrower type for your `Moveable` class;
2. Incorporate some concept of coordinate systems and conversions into your class.